# How can i have only 1 ip address in outbound addresses for an Azure web App?

Tags: azure

In Azure web app there are a number of outbound ip addresses. Clients need to whitelist these addresses to be able to access the web site.
Is there a way i can have only one ip address in the outbound and keep it at all times for that website , sort of like a static ip address ?

I have tried creating a new site and seeing what it does , but a number of addresses are created .

UPDATE:
Steps taken:

```
1. Create a virtual network (keep values as default) and created a subnet
```

2. created a NAT and associated with the subnet of the  VNet
3. Set the Outbound IP in the Nat gateway as one of the 32 outbound ips of the web app
4. In the web app under VNate i created a VNaet and selected the created Vnate above and the gate way from above aswell.
   Thats it .

Now if clients only whitelist the Outbound IP in the NAT the regardless of the request it should still be ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with an App Service, there's this:

> ### Get a static outbound IP
>
> You can control the IP address of outbound traffic from your app by using regional VNet integration together with a virtual network NAT gateway to direct traffic through a static public IP address. [Regional VNet integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration) is available on Basic, Standard, Premium, PremiumV2 and PremiumV3 App Service plans. To learn more about this setup, see [NAT gateway integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/nat-gateway-integration).

Source: [Inbound and outbound IP addresses in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips)

Comment: so i need to setup a VNet and NAT ?

Comment: If you want one static outbound IP for an App Service: yes. The most important reason: your app service could roam the data center. Without setting up VNET and NAT, you will have multiple outbound IPs. The VNET and NAT tie the IP to the app service.

Comment: great will try this approach and get back to you . thanks

Comment: oh are there step by step details in doing this ?

Comment: Check the second link in the quote :)

Comment: this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/nat-gateway-integration

Comment: I tried this but cant seem to get a single ip address

Comment: When i create it , should i see only 1 ip address in outbound for my web app ?

Comment: Please take into account this is not the place to ask for a step-by-step walkthrough of this process. The documentation I linked to has that, and in step 7 it states "You can see the public IP that your app will use for outbound Internet-facing traffic in the Outbound IP blade". You should be good to go!

Comment: yes ok, but when i create it , should i see only 1 ip address in outbound for my web app ?

Comment: I have configured according to the above answer. I am testing from my windows machine. It gives Forbidden. Do i need to whitelist the new outbound ip address ?

Comment: I put a "Access restriction" , is that required ?

Comment: I have outlined what i did in the question above

Comment: I followed your steps in conjunction with this video     https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4GCTX4Qzzk   Hence i ask do we need "Access restriction"